# target device not found android error usb device option selected

Tags: android

I have tried an Android project on Lollipop and I have enabled Developer Mode on the Lollipop device.I have also selected USB device in Run->Edit Confidurations.But I still got the error:No target device found.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you enable USB Debugging on your device?

Answer (score 0):

Disable your antivirus! , then reinstall ADB driver for your mobile device. 
You can get driver from here adbdriver.com/downloads.
it worked for me.